# How to show selected item in Syncfusion DropDownList control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application using Syncfusion controls. I have a drop down list in my view. The model has a property "Categories" which is a List of type Category.

```
public class Category
{
    public int XKategorieId { get; set; }
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Hinweis { get; set; }
    public string Kategorie { get; set; }
}
```

The model of the view also has a property "IdFromCategory". The model is:

```
public class ReportModel
{
    public int? IdFromCategory { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I am showing all the categories in the drop down list by setting the "DataSource" of "DropDownList". Now, my issue is that i want to show an item selected in the "DropDownList" when the view loads and that selected item will be the one with "Id" equals to "IdFromCategory ".

```
@Html.EJS().DropDownList("KundenBetreuung").DataSource(Model.Categories).Fields(new Syncfusion.EJ2.DropDowns.DropDownListFieldSettings { Text = "Kategorie", Value = "Id" }).Value(Model.IdFromCategory.ToString()).Width("100%").Render();
```

This is my code, i am unable to set the selected item in the "DropDownList"

Comment: This is not what i am looking for @JohnB. Your link is saying how to retrieve the selected value but i have to set a selected value on the basis of Id when screen loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Razor code, you have filled the value property with **Model.IdFromCategory.ToString()** (a string) where the declared properties **IdFromCategory** and **Id** both are integers. This mismatching type is the cause of the issue in your end and the value is not being set. To successfully set the value make sure that the value provided is available in the datasource and its type matches as well.

Suggest changing the code as follows

```
@Html.EJS().DropDownList("KundenBetreuung").DataSource(Model.Categories).Fields(new Syncfusion.EJ2.DropDowns.DropDownListFieldSettings { Text = "Kategorie", Value = "Id" }).Value(Model.IdFromCategory).Width("100%").Render();
```

Check the following example for further reference
[Example](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/WebApplication11071726385)